# Jquery dialog pop up updates multiple row records?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this jquery pop up update code

```
   $(document).on("click", ".editButton", function () {

      //Opens the update pops up menu.
        $("#dialogupdate").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,

            width: 890,
            height: 620,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "fold",
                duration: 1000
            }
        });
```

here is the html code for one column

```
<div id="dialogupdate" title="Update Problem Log" style="display: none;">
    <form id="myidupdate" name="myidupdate" method="post">
    <table class="updatetable">
        <tr>
            <td> 
    <tr>
            <td>
                PROD DATE:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtproddate-up" name="cpname" style="margin-left: 10px; color: Black;" />
                <span style="font-family: Arial Narrow; font-size: Medium;">(e.g MAY14)</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

and it loads id for each records using JavaScript.

```
table = table + '<td><input type="button" style="width:40px;  color:White; background color:#00BFFF;" class="editButton" value="Edit" id="' + obj[i].MANUAL_RUN_ID + '"/></td>';
```

and in update click side

```
$("#btnUpdate").click(function () {
  var newupdateId = testObject.attr('id');
var proddate = $('#txtproddate-up').val();
```

and i pass this to ajax call .  but somehow it makes double time inserting here if i do the action below.

I have 3 rows displays on the table and each one has edit buttons .When I click one of edit buttons and menu gets open and I close it. next step , i click another edit button and update some record .so result is , it updates both row records . Any help appreciate [image]

Comment: can you show us some HTML as well please?

Comment: Can we get the update code for the dialog?  Also, can we get the HTML that is generated?  I'm going to go out on a limb and say that you probably are selecting multiple rows in your jQuery row selection.  I would sugest using Angularjs for something like that, then you just need to modify the view model and everything gets updated accordingly

Comment: I don't see the `.editButton` - can you add more HTML?

Comment: I updated my question.. hope this works for you to get an idea.

Comment: It is mostly likely an html break. Please check if all the divs are properly being closed. Can you also check what the the div id/class of the newly generated row items

Comment: they are fine. but it seems like I have to something in dialog code like , function .hide()

Comment: Can you show the code where EDIT buttons are added dynamically.. I think issue is with the edit button's IDs

Comment: Yes. I thing so. I displayed it already starts "table = table +"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the testObject id attribute everytime you click on the edit button. So that when you reading same in update call, you will get the proper id.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see any more of your code it sounds like you need to set the rows to unique id's. Try passing `$(this).attr('id');`